# In Osmdroid, is there a way to rotate the label text for places on the map?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am using open street maps for android and rotating the map. However, when doing so, the labels for places become upside down. I was wondering if there is a way to also rotate the map labels.

I am rotating the map as follows:

```
map.setMapOrientation(degrees);
```

Comment: osmdroid uses map tiles that are small bitmap images. The place names are part of a bitmap, so any text in a map tile is rotated along with everything else.